# React use the arrow keys to navigate between each NavLink

Tags: reactjs

I needed a way to navigate between each Navlink in my menu with the arrow keys.
The fastest way I've found is to use ReactDOM.findDOMNode (however, you have to forget the DOM with react!)
I know...
I show you my code, can you tell me how you would have done please? I'm sure I'm wrong, even if it works very well

```
      const findActiveNavLink = () => {
        var node = document.querySelector('[aria-current="page"]');
        return ReactDOM.findDOMNode(node);
      };
    
  useEffect(() => {
    if (leftPress) {
      const active = findActiveNavLink();
      const next = active.parentNode.previousSibling;
      next !== null && next.hasChildNodes() && next.children.item(0).click();
    }
  }, [leftPress]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (rightPress) {
      const active = findActiveNavLink();
      const next = active.parentNode.nextSibling;
      next !== null && next.hasChildNodes() && next.children.item(0).click();
    }
  }, [rightPress]);
```

Comment: just to clarify, when you say `Navlink` you mean when you press an arrow key say left, the page navigates to that page or you mean when you press left, you simply mve the the link on the left?

Comment: I mean the page navigates yes, it's like my main menu becomes a slider (only with keyboard).

Comment: You could place your menu items into an array. Then figure out how to switch between indexes. Once that's covered you could add some rendering logic in your jsx that  renders your menu item components based on button press. You'd probably want to look into `useEffect`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you Sebastian Bbudje, I've done this by this way :

```
  const location = useLocation();
  const { pathname } = location;
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const menu = [
    {
      to: "/",
      name: "Accueil",
      action: "restartSlider",
    },
    {
      to: "/coming-soon",
      name: "Services",
    },
    {
      to: "/coming-soon",
      name: "Portfolio",
    },
    {
      to: "/coming-soon",
      name: "Team",
    },
    {
      to: "mailto:hello@mysite.fr",
      name: "Contact",
    },
  ];

  const useMenu = (current, direction) => {
    if (Array.isArray(current)) {
      const index = current.findIndex((current) => current.to === pathname);
      direction === "right"
        ? index + 1 !== 2 && navigate(current[index + 1].to)
        : index - 1 !== -1 && navigate(current[index - 1].to);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (leftPress) {
      useMenu(menu, "left");
    }
  }, [leftPress]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (rightPress) {
      useMenu(menu, "right");
    }
  }, [rightPress]);
```

and :

```
            {menu.map((current) => {
              return (
                <li
                  key={current.name}
                  className={"navbar__item"}
                >
                  <NavLink
                    to={current.to}
                    onClick={(event) => useMenu(current)}
                  >
                    {current.name}
                  </NavLink>
                </li>
              );
            })}
```

Because I'm using useNavigate, no need to create additional classes because navlink does that very well.